# C++ Thread blocks Main-Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, boost-thread

**Problem:** When the ExecuteQueue Function get's called there's already two existing Packets in Queue and they get called correctly (printed to console). But even though the ExecuteQueue Function get's looped in another Thread the Main Thread is blocked (It never gets to QueuePacket).

I already browsed stackoverflow and most Issues were related to .join but this one probably isn't (removing the .join makes no difference).

**Main.cpp**

```
int main() { 
    // Start Client
    boost::thread tClient(&Networking::Client::Initialize, Networking::Client()); // Still in Main-Thread???!?!?
    Networking::Client::QueuePacket(Networking::Packet::Types::Disconnect);

    // Start Modules
    tClient.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**Client.cpp** (Only the necessary Functions)

```
    static bool QueuePacket(Packet p) { // Pushes existing Packet
        return Globals::Queue.push(p);
    }

    void ExecuteQueue() {
        while (Client::Active && Globals::NetworkConnectivity) {
            if (Globals::Queue.empty()) { Sleep(500); continue; }

            Packet p(Packet::Types::Invalid);
            if (!Globals::Queue.pop(p)) continue; // Copies Packet into p on Success
            if (p.Type == Packet::Types::Disconnect) { Client::Active = false; } // Disconnects Queue
            if (p.Type == Packet::Types::Invalid) { } // Find some error handling here

            ExecutePacket(p);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: @tambre I'll take an educated guess and say it's how do you prevent blocking the main-thread...?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Networking::Client* ClientPtr = new Networking::Client();
    boost::thread tClient(&Networking::Client::Initialize, ClientPtr);
```

This works.